# using Self-Signed SSL certificate with WCF ws2007FederationBinding

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I'm at my wit's end, and I'm hoping you can help me. I'm trying to get active WS-Trust authentication going with WIF from a web application to a web service, using a self-signed certificate.

I've already tried the following:

1) Install certificate in machine certificate store under Trusted Root Certification Authorities, Personal, and Trusted People

2) Make sure 'Everyone' has full access to Crypto/RSA/MachineKeys folder

3) Override certificate validation with  `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, to a method that just returns `true`. I can debug into this method and watch it return true.

And I *STILL* see this in the System.ServiceModel trace:

[0832] SecureChannel#66940002 - Certificate name mismatch.

[0832] SecureChannel#66940002 - Remote certificate was verified as invalid by the user.

And the application blows up with:
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ServerCertificateValidationCallback only does the SSL related part of the certificate verification.

So if it's still broken, this means there **not only** SSL at play here.

In fact WS-Trust is build on top of WS-Security and WS-Security does a signature of the headers of your message,. And the verification of that signature is not impacted by *ServerCertificateValidationCallback*.

You certainly have a second certificate signing the WS Security headers of your message.

There's a different piece of code that verifies if the name of that certificates matches the value in the identity node of the endpoint settings, as below :

```
<endpoint address="..." 
    <identity>
      <dns value="PUT CN OF THE MESSAGE SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE HERE" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

If in addition the message signature certificate doesn't validate, you can disable it's validation by modifying "behaviors/endpointBehaviors/behavior/clientCredentials/serviceCertificate/authentication". 
You set the certificateValidationMode attribute there to "None".

Or you set it to Custom, and will have then to implement your own validator, that derives from System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator and overrides the Validate callback.